# Terminal dies in OSX after opening serial ports

Tags: c#, macos, mono, serial-port, xamarin

Executing this code works as you'd expect, *but* the terminal session gets wonky as the method returns.
It does work from MonoDevelop (and I have something similar in Windows with no problem), but when calling from bash "mono program.exe" it doesn't. It works until I get the prompt again, the prompt looks right but I can't do anything with it, it is completely frozen.

I am running Xamarin Studio 4.0.1 in Lion. The .Net target doesn't seem to matter.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace relay
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames ();

            foreach (string name in ports) {
                try {
                    SerialPort port = new SerialPort (name, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                    port.Open ();
                    port.Close ();
                }
                catch (SystemException ex)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Going through it again I've found out that it doesn't freeze, but text input is not visible (I can blindly type "ls" and see the directory) and the return character doesn't put the prompt back to the leftmost bottom corner, the next prompt appears directly after the last commands' text output.

Comment: Looking into the list of ports I see /dev/ttys000 listed, which reminds me of the names used for terminal ports.. could it be I am breaking the port assigned to the terminal I am using?